# how to disable scrolling in HTML files in iPad web

Tags: css, html

I am using following code for my webpage but i have removed script but it still page swaping is with finger for ipad how to remove this. I have removed all the scripts but again it is swaping.I have tried

```
<body scroll='no'>
```

but does not get any response

HTML file code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="draxxin.manifest">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png" />
    <title>BRD</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.2.6.css"
    />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="images/favicon.gif" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"
    />
    <link type="text/css" href="newstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function showHideDiv()
        {
            document.getElementById("one").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("two").style.visibility = "visible";

            document.getElementById("three").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("four").style.visibility = "hidden";


        }
    </script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function showHideView()
        {

            document.getElementById("one").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("two").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("three").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("four").style.visibility = "visible";



        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $(".linkbutton").click(function ()
            {
                /* <!--   var address= $(this).attr("src");-->*/
                var address = $(this).attr("data-light");


                $("#popup").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#lightbox").attr("src", address);
            });
            $("#close").click(function ()
            {
                $("#popup").fadeOut("fast");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $(".linkbutton_one").click(function ()
            {
                /* <!--   var address= $(this).attr("src");-->*/
                var address = $(this).attr("data-light-one");


                $("#popup_one").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#lightbox_one").attr("src", address);
            });
            $("#close_one").click(function ()
            {
                $("#popup_one").fadeOut("fast");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $(".linkbutton_two").click(function ()
            {

                /* <!--   var address= $(this).attr("src");-->*/



                var address = $(this).attr("data-light-two");


                $("#popup_two").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#lightbox_two").attr("src", address);
            });
            $("#close_two").click(function ()
            {
                $("#popup_two").fadeOut("fast");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #popup {
            background:#FFFFFF;
            height:75%;
            width: 100%;
            position:absolute;
            display: none;
        }
        #center {
            border: 10px solid #121212;
            margin: 6% 0 0 20%;
            width: 572px;
        }
        #close {
            float: right;
            position:absolute;
            margin:25px 0px 0 0;
            top:0px;
            left:510px;
        }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
        #popup_one {
            background:#FFFFFF;
            height:100%;
            width: 100%;
            position:absolute;
            display: none;
        }
        #center_one {
            border: 10px solid #121212;
            margin: 6% 0 0 20%;
            width: 318px;
        }
        #close_one {
            float: right;
            position:absolute;
            margin:25px 0px 0 0;
            top:0px;
            left:510px;
        }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
        #popup_two {
            background:#FFFFFF;
            height:100%;
            width: 100%;
            position:absolute;
            display: none;
        }
        #center_two {
            border: 10px solid #121212;
            margin: 6% 0 0 20%;
            width: 318px;
        }
        #close_two {
            float: right;
            position:absolute;
            position:relative;
            margin:25px 0px 0 0;
            top:0px;
            left:510px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<BODY onLoad="showHideDiv()">

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="page_one" class="panel">
                <div class="main_heading">Overview</div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="stix"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#page_one"><img src="image/overview_active.png"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="stix"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#page_two"><img src="image/strategy.gif"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="stix"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><img src="image/draxxin.gif"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="stix"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><img src="image/excede.gif"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="stix"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><img src="image/results.gif"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="stix"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><img src="image/reference.gif"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="stix"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="rightclass">
                    <img src="image/pageone_image.png" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="midmenu">
                            <a href="index.html"><img src="image/backward.png"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <!--#page_one-->
                        <li class="midmenu1">
                            <a href="#page_two"><img src="image/forward.png"/></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="text_paragraph">
                    <p>Bovine Respiratory Disease (BRD) is the leading cause of economic loss
                        in the beef industry.
                        <small>1, 2</small>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="text_paragraph_1">
                    <b>Economic loss:</b>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Costs the industry an estimated $1 billion each year.
                            <small>3, 4</small>
                        </li>
                        <li>Losses can be attributed to death, reduced feed and treatment costs.
                            <small>3,4</small>
                        </li>
                        <li>Economic losses range from an estimated $57.48 to $239.69 per head.
                            <small>1, 2</small>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="text_paragraph_2">
                    <b>Bacterial Culprits:</b>
                    <p>Four bacterial pathogens are commonly associated with BRD.</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Mannheimia haemolytica</li>
                        <li>Pasteurella multocida</li>
                        <li>Histophilus somni</li>
                        <li>Mycoplasma bovis</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="image/smallicon_2.png" class="linkbutton">
                    <img src="image/smallicon_2.png" class="linkbutton" data-light="image/popup_page_1.png"
                    />
                </div>
                <div id="popup">
                    <div id="center">
                        <img id="lightbox" src="image/popup_page_1.png">
                        <img id="close" src="images/close.png" alt="close">
                    </div>
                    <!-- #center -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End of page one-->
            <div id="page_two" class="panel">
                <div class="main_heading_two">Strategy</div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="stix"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#page_one"><img src="image/overview.gif" /></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="stix"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#page_two"><img src="image/strategy_active.png"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="stix"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><img src="image/draxxin.gif"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="stix"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><img src="image/excede.gif"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="stix"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><img src="image/results.gif"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="stix"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><img src="image/reference.gif"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="stix"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="rightclass_one">
                    <img src="image/whiteslide.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="pagetwo_text">
                    <p>Get up to 21 days of BRD therapy strategy using longer-duration antimicrobials
                        DRAXXIN ® (tulathromycin) Injectable Solution and EXCEDE ® (ceftiofur crystalline
                        free acid) Sterile Suspension.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="pagetwo_list_text">Advantages for Producers:
                    <ul>
                        <li>Fewer treatments</li>
                        <li>Less stress on cattle</li>
                        <li>Fewer mortalities</li>
                        <li>Cattle can recover in their own pen</li>
                        <li>Lower treatment costs and higher profits</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="pagetwo_list_text2">Extended duration strategy</div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="midmenu_1">
                            <a href="#page_one"><img src="image/backward.png"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="midmenu_2">
                            <a href="#page_two"><img src="image/forward.png"/></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="right_text">
                    <p>Either way you use them, it takes both DRAXXIN and EXCEDE for control
                        and treatment of BRD in high-risk cattle to give you the longest duration
                        of BRD therapy</p>
                </div>
                <div class="image_21">
                    <img src="image/pagetwo_graph_two_4.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="ratemeter">
                    <img src="image/pagetwo_graph_one.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="one" class="image_one">
                    <img src="image/optiononetwo.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="two" class="image_two">
                    <img src="image/optiononeone.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="three" class="image_one_one">
                    <img src="image/pagetwo_graph_two_11.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="four" class="image_two_two">
                    <img src="image/pagetwo_graph_two_22.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="option_image">
                    <img src="image/option_1.png" onclick="showHideDiv()" />
                </div>
                <div class="option_image_label">Option 1</div>
                <div class="option_image_one">
                    <img src="image/option_1.png" onclick="showHideView()" />
                </div>
                <div class="option_image_label_one">Option 2</div>
                <div class="fourteen_day">
                    <img src="image/button_14days.PNG" />
                </div>
                <div class="heading_one">Post Metaphylaxis Interval (PMI)</div>
                <div>
                    <img src="image/smallicon_1.png" class="linkbutton_one">
                    <img src="image/smallicon_1.png" class="linkbutton_one" data-light-one="image/popup_2_page_2.png"
                    />
                </div>
                <div id="popup_one">
                    <div id="center_one">
                        <img id="lightbox_one" src="image/popup_2_page_2.png">
                        <img id="close_one" src="images/close.png" alt="close">
                    </div>
                    <!-- #center -->
                </div>
                <div class="seven_day">
                    <img src="image/button_7days.PNG" />
                </div>
                <div class="heading_two">Post Treatment Interval (PTI)</div>
                <!-- <div class="linkbutton_two">
        <a href="image/popup_2_page_2.png" rel="lightbox"><img src="image/smallicon_1.png"  alt="" /></a>
       </div>
        -->
                <div>
                    <img src="image/smallicon_1.png" class="linkbutton_two">
                    <img src="image/smallicon_1.png" class="linkbutton_two" data-light-two="image/popup_2_page_2.png"
                    />
                </div>
                <div id="popup_two">
                    <div id="center_two">
                        <img id="lightbox_two" src="image/popup_2_page_2.png">
                        <img id="close_two" src="images/close.png" alt="close">
                    </div>
                    <!-- #center -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End of page two-->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just hide the scrolling

```
<style>
    body, html { overflow: hidden; }
</style>
```

Comment: where to write this inside <body ,html{overflow:hidden;}> like this

Comment: i have tried this but again there is scrolling of page working

Comment: Do you have a demo of the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292522/how-to-disable-scrolling-in-html-files-in-ipad-web

Comment: this is the code of my question i also posted earlier but did not get any response

Comment: @JacksonJ, Why did you repost the question? Merge the two questions and delete one of them?

Comment: But Will the page be correct fix to window if I make overflow hidden? I think that it just hides the scrollbar.